# Finding the cdf from pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was reading up on finding the cdf from a pdf, and noticed that my cdf did not satisfy the condition of $F_Y{(−1)}=0$ and $F_Y{(1)} = 1$. Given the equation $f_Y(y) = cy^2(1-y)1_{[0,1]}(y)$ I calculated the cdf to be $\frac{1}{12}(4-3x)x^3$ by integrating the pdf: $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{12}y^2(1-y)dy$. However this integral does not satisfy the above conditions, so I was hoping to see if someone could point out what I did wrong.

Comment: "$F_Y{(−1)}=0$" should be $F_Y{(0)}=0$ because the support of the pdf is $[0,1]$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Ah i did not know that. So the cdf should be 0 for the endpoints of the range?

Comment: only for the leftmost one. for the rightmost one it should be 1.

Comment: @jean-marie: Then there would be no need for $1_{[0,1]}$

Comment: @gammatester No : $1_{[0,1]}$ should still be necessary for the pdf.

Comment: @jean-marie: Why? For $y\not \in [0,1]$ it would be undefined. But I agree that $F(0)=0$ would be clearer.

Comment: @gammatester This option of considering a pdf as "undefined" outside its support has some disadvantages, in particular when you have different random variables. It is preferable to associate a domain through the multiplication by an indicator function $1_I$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pdf is $12 \cdot y^2 (1-y)$. You have the wrong proportionality constant.

Comment: I am not a smart man. So is the correct cdf $(4-3x)x^3$?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: Looks like the support is $[-1,1],$ then the PDF is
 is $f_Y(y) = 12y^2(1-y)1_{[0,1]}(y).$ Your function has $\int_{-1}^1 = 8$

Comment: @gammatester I think the support is [0, 1] as indicated by the indicator function in $f(y)$.